# CodeLite IDE is not reading file

Tags: c++, codelite

So I have a Test folder inside my workspace in CodeLite and inside Test folder I have:

main.cpp

test.txt

The problem is whenever I try to read from test.txt, the compiler deletes the file content and writes "Debug/main.cpp.o" inside my test.txt file. For example, if my txt file contains the following text:

> Abcd ef

And my code inside main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    string data;
    ifstream infile; 
    infile.open("text.txt"); 
     
    cout << "Reading from the file" << endl; 
    infile >> data; 
    return 0;
    
}
```

When I run my code the output should be:

```
Reading from file 
Abcd
ef
```

But instead, the output is:

```
Reading from file
```

And now my test.txt contains:

> Debug/main.cpp.o

I am also inserting what my folder contains:
[image]

I don't know why it does this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codelite generates `$(project).txt` (`$(project)` is `Test` in your case) with all objects filename for compilation (as [response file](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Response_Files) (to bypass limit of command line length when there are too many files)).

Either place project in another directory or rename the file or project to avoid the conflict with that file.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you haven't use/printed the data variable.
Use this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string data;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("test.txt");

    cout<<"Reading from file"<<endl;

    while (getline(infile,data))
    {
        cout<<data<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The same thing happened.

Comment: Try pasting the Test.txt in the folder where the executable is generated.

Comment: Also tried this. But that didn't really work too.